# (CLion/CMake) Why does my c file not belong to any target project when it is saved within the project directory?

Tags: c, cmake, directory, clion

Preface: I am very new to c and CLion, so apologies in advance if my phrasing is very wrong.

Essentially, I have an assignment that involves two c files (a "main", and one performing a conversion between imperial and metric units). The main c file simply #include-s the conversion file, performs a function within the conversion file, and prints the resulting value to the user. Simple enough, but I keep getting a message every time I try to run it:

*"undefined reference to 'conversion'"*

I have tried to suss out the problem, and my only idea relates to the banner at the top of conversion.c which says *"This file does not belong to any project target, code insight features may not work properly."*. I do not understand why I receive this message, because conversion.c and main.c are both within the main project directory, and this setup worked perfectly fine in my previous assignment.

I have searched for solutions online, and the only one that seemed to make sense was to update my CMakeLists.txt file to include *add_executable(project conversion.c)*. This is what my CMakeLists.txt file looks like before I add this line:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(project C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(project main.c)
```

However, when I add it, I get the error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (add_executable):
add_executable cannot create target "directory" because another
target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is an
executable created in source directory
"/home/john_s/CLionProjects/project".  See documentation for
policy CMP0002 for more details.
```

Presumably this is because the previous line I have (*add_executable(project main.c)*) is linking to the same directory, but I have no idea how to resolve this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You error references CMakeLists.txt line __7__, yet you posted a CMakeLists.txt file with 6 lines. Also the error is prety self explenatory. You need to explicitly tell cmake by `file(GLOB_RECURSE src dir/*.c) add_executable(project_name ${srcs})` to add all sources to an executable. And cmake does not allow to create targets/executables with the same name. The "directory" is not a directory, it's a target name.

Comment: The CMakeLists.txt file is 6 lines long originally, but then I add the a new line "add_executable(project conversion.c)" and then the CMake error occurs.

I have tried to add the suggested lines, but I have never used those before so I am encountering some errors. Is "srcs" where I put the c file names? If so, I can't seem to find a way to include multiple names there.

Comment: You can't have two executable named the same. You just `add_executable(project main.c conversion.c)` is that what you mean? You can put your sources in any folder and directory and path you want.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry, I didn't know you could put two .c files in the same add_executable(...) line. That solved the CMake error, though, and the program now compiles correctly, so thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

From [cmake manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/add_executable.html):

> add_executable(< name> [WIN32] [MACOSX_BUNDLE]
>                  [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL]
>                  [source1] [source2 ...])
>
> Adds an executable target called  to be built from the source files listed in the command invocation. (The source files can be omitted here if they are added later using target_sources().)

So to combile a single executable using two source files, you just use:

```
add_executable(target_name source1.c source2.c)
```